# Physical Interrupt Line Sharing Between Multiple Peripherals

Tags: arm, interrupt

I am reading arm GIC specification. It's mentioned that Shared Peripheral Interrupt(SPI) - Interrupt ID 32-1019 is one of the Peripheral Interrupt Type. Initially, i was thinking that each of these Peripherals Interrupts type physical Lines can be shared among Multiple peripherals. But later i realised that these interrupts type are shared between all the CPU Cores (In case of Multicore Processor). Since, it is clearly mentioned in specification that in a uniprocessor system, there is no distinction between shared and private peripheral interrupts, because all interrupts are visible to the processor.

My Question is : How the Interrupt Lines are Physically Shared between Multiple Peripherals ?

For eg: I am designing a system and want to share the Interrupt Line say 50, between 2 peripherals USB Host and Ethernet card? Is it possible to share the SPI Line with peripherals ? if yes, How should i configure GIC to achieve this ?

Comment: Nobody's going to stop you from wiring an appropriate logical combination of peripheral interrupt outputs to the same GIC input; it's got nothing to do with configuring the GIC itself. Just be aware that muxing unrelated interrupts together is likely to lead to software developers hating you and choosing a different system instead (because having an indistinct "something happened!" interrupt and having to go off and poll everything to find out who raised it rather defeats the point of having an interrupt controller in the first place).

Comment: @Notlikethat: Thank you for the response. I can visualise the things now. One more doubt, is it possible to share the SPI lines only between Multiple Peripherals ? Or PPI's can also be shared between Peripherals (If incase the Peripherals interrupts are targeted to a particular Core) ?

Comment: It's all just inputs and outputs; you can wire whatever you like to whatever you like provided it meets your timing/fanout/etc. constraints. Whether it's _useful_ to do so, or _feasible_ for mainstream software to work with the result, is another matter.